# acessing columns relevant to dynamic table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

i have been having trouble solving what seems to me a complex aspect of plsql, I have a table1 with a list of table_names and a table2 with backups to those table_names

Table1

```
id name max_rows    date            
1    a      100    2018-10-06        
2    b      100    2018-10-06         
3    c      100    2018-10-06
```

Table2

```
 id     name_bck          FK date_created date closed      
 1          a_bck          1  
 2          b_bck          2          
 3          c_bck          3
```

so the idea is for me to insert rows from a onto a_bck until a_bck reaches its limit (max_rows) then i would create a new a_bck2 and close(update close date from table2);

the problem im having is i cant access columns from table a of my table1, i want to insert data from a to a_bck  where its date column from table a is < then sysdate

so i created 2 cursors to go through both tables and return the data i need to perform operations over.

```
cursor c1 is
select id name max_rows from table1 where date<sysdate;



curso2 c2 is
select id_fk , name, from table2 where table1.id=table2.id_fk and close_date is null;
```

then i would loop through and fetch the data related to table1 and table2

```
fetch c1 into id, n_tab, n_rows;


FETCH c2 INTO id_fk, n_tab2;
```

I would like some help on how to dynamically access the columns from the tables on table1.

I tried to summarize the best way possible.

If anyone could show me a small example of how i could implement this.

PS: i cant use partitions

Thank you in advance

Comment: You'll need to use dynamic SQL queries for this. See e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm.

Comment: And if you are trying to figure out the column present in the tables, check out https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2091.htm#I1020277.

Comment: @HenningKoehler thanks for the feedback, to implement what i pretend, i would need a new cursor that would go through the table_columns and pick out the one i need? for example all the tables i have on table1 have a common column called criado_em, which is the date is was created on, i want to pick out data depending on the date.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly - are you trying to copy only some of the rows in tables listed in table1 over into their matching backup tables, based on the value of column criado_em (so decided row-by-row)? If so then you can just  incorporate that check into the insert statement you run for each table.

Comment: @HenningKoehler that is exactly what i need, to me its still a very complex process since i have started working with oracle only a little while back, i tried using that in the insert statement but incorrectly , since i dont know how to access the column 'criado_em' from the tables on table1

Comment: @HenningKoehler i had something like stmt_ins:= 'INSERT into ' || n_tab2 || ' SELECT * FROM ' || n_tab || ' where ''' || criado_em  || '< :dt';

execute immediate stmt_ins using sysdate;

Problem is i get an error since i dont have access to criado_em from n_tab(variable of the table name from table1)

Comment: Why are you trying to evaluate criado_em while building the string, rather than using `... || 'where criado_em < :dt'`?

Comment: @HenningKoehler you are right, i was trying something different, but i tried that before, and still cant return any rows.

i get the output INSERT into HS_TESTES_2 SELECT * FROM sii_bck_logs.HS_TESTES where criado_em< :dt

Comment: If by output you mean the value of `stmt_ins`, then this looks correct. And your query is an insert query, so wouldn't return any rows - do you mean it doesn't insert anything even though there is something to insert?

Comment: So you're still persisting with this half-cooked process? You do know that Oracle comes with a complete Backup and Recovery solution, which is not only free but also fully-supported? [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/toc.htm)

Comment: @HenningKoehler got it working, thanks for your help, i was just wondering what is the best way i can rollback in case something goes wrong on my insert?

Comment: If you want to rollback while testing with oracle client, turn auto-commit off and you can just issue a `rollback` command.

Comment: @HenningKoehler when i execute immediate does it commit instantly? Sorry about all the questions, but im new to oracle, and its a lot of info to take in.

Comment: In principle, you need to commit for any changes to become persistent, otherwise they'll be rolled back once your session ends. However, most DB clients (including Oracle) have an "autocommit" setting turned on by default, meaning the client automatically sends a commit after every command.

Comment: @HenningKoehler so if i have a rollback in a exception during insert , will will the rollback still work or is it pointless to have since it always commits?